# how to count a specific number from a file in c++

Tags: c++

Yes, this is a question for a class, but I don't want my homework done for me.  I just need to figure out where I'm going wrong.  The question that I have to figure out states this:

***Write a program which uses the file produced in Lab 1 as its input file.  This program gets user input of a value from 1000 to 10000, and counts how many times the user's value appears in the input file.  It reports to the user using screen output.***

Here's the code that I have after several failed attempts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int count(int number, int input, int length)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if(input == number)
            counter++;
    return counter;
}

int main()
{
    int num,input;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("ran_num.txt");
    if(fin.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Input file opening failed."<<endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    cout<<"Enter a number between 1000 to 10000:";
    cin>>num;

    fin>>input;

    cout<<num<<"appears "<<count(num, input, 3000)<<" times in the file."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm completely lost and just need to figure out what I use to count a user inputer value.  Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**
This is what I have now.  My program can now read the whole file, but I still do not know how to count a user-inputted number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("ran_num.txt");
    int num, user_input;

    cout<<"Enter a number between 1000 to 10000:";
    cin>>user_input;

    while(fin>>num)
    {
        if(num == user_input)
        {
            cout<<count++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your program doing that is incorrect?

Comment: Take the code that you've shown in your question, and [explain your code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I have full confidence that your rubber duck will be able to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: when I run the program it doesn't count the number that I input.  I make sure I input a number thats in the file at least once and it outputs that number shows up 0 times every time.

Comment: I see exactly one statement in your program that reads the first line from the file. Aren't you supposed to read the entire file, and search for every occurence of the target number in the file? Where's your code that reads every line in the file?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik okay let me figure out how to fix that.  I didn't realize I wasn't reading the whole file.  My professor hasn't taught us any of this is and is really making the class struggle in this first week.

Comment: This is why I advised you to explain every line of your code to your rubber duck. It is your rubber duck's responsibility to analyze your code. I now fully expect to have to deal with a grievance from the International Brotherhood Of Rubber Ducks union representative this week. Sigh... No good deed goes unpunished...

Comment: Did you ask your professor? Did not he tell the class that `fin >> input` needs to be in a loop? Where on each iteration, it reads a number (line) and compares it, then takes a new number (line) and compares it.. etc. I doubt that he did not.

Comment: @FirstStep Unfortunately she didn't, but I did figure out how to read the entire file through googling.  Now I just need to figure out how to find how many time the user inputed integer occurs in the file.

Comment: Do you mind adding `int count = 0;` to properly declare and initialize that variable in your last snippet? Then in the loop keep only `++count;` and print the value only after.

Comment: Are there only integer numbers in the input file? No text?

Comment: @Bob__ yes it's only integers.  I can add the edits that you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code that I have.  It works perfectly now thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("ran_num.txt");
    int num, user_input, count;

    cout<<"Please enter a number from 1000 to 10000:";
    cin>>user_input;

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        while (fin >> num)
        {
            if (num == user_input)
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        fin.close();
        cout<<user_input<<" occurs "<<count<<" times.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open file.";
    }

    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your program is opening the file?
You should check if the file is opened correctly, you also should close the file after use.
Also you're outputting `count` before incrementing it.
I suggest changing your `while` loop this way:

```
if (fin.is_open())
{
    while (fin >> num)
    {
        if (num == user_input)
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << count;
}
else
{
    cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```